# How do I put arrows inside circle in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need your help in creating the following figure in tikz. I am absolute beginner in tikz. 
[image]

I saw the example in the following page, but I need it the way as shown in the picture which I could not produce 
[TikZ: Using Loop to Draw Grid of Nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61805/tikz-using-loop-to-draw-grid-of-nodes)

Comment: Try `\node [circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] {$\downarrow$};`.

Comment: Do you want to know how to put arrows inside circles in TikZ or how do create that figure?

Comment: I am finding it difficult to draw the complete picture, so it would be nice if you can tell me how to create the complete figure. I came to know about tikz just yesterday and the learning curve seems a bit higher. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this code can help you. It's not possible to apply the code from your link because we don't know if the position of the arrows are automatic or not. A large part needs to be draw by manually. The next code is not very elegant but you can try to do something better.
A fine idea is to determine the coordinates of all the nodes before drawing the grid with a loop like in the link without define nodes (only coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    down/.style={path picture={
     \draw[->]  ([yshift=-3pt]path picture bounding box.north)  
             -- ([yshift=3pt]path picture bounding box.south);}},
    up/.style={path picture={
      \draw[->]  ([yshift=3pt]path picture bounding box.south)  
              -- ([yshift=-3pt]path picture bounding box.north);}},
    every node/.style={circle,draw, minimum size=1 cm}]

    \node[label=45:$1$,up]   (n-1-1)          {};
    \node[label=45:$2$,down] (n-1-2) at (2,0) {};
    \node[label=45:$3$,up]   (n-1-3) at (4,0) {};
    \node[label=45:$n$,up]   (n-1-4) at (6,0) {};

    \node[label=45:$n+1$,down] (n-2-1)  at (0,-2) {};
    \node[label=45:$n+2$,up]   (n-2-2)  at (2,-2) {};
    \node[label=45:$n+3$,down] (n-2-3)  at (4,-2) {};
    \node[label=45:$n+4$,up]   (n-2-4)  at (6,-2) {};

    \node[up]   (n-3-1)  at (0,-4)  {};
    \node[up]   (n-3-2)  at (2,-4)  {};
    \node[down] (n-3-3)  at (4,-4)  {};
    \node[down] (n-3-4)  at (6,-4)  {};

    \node[up]   (n-4-1)  at (0,-6) {};
    \node[down] (n-4-2)  at (2,-6) {};
    \node[up]   (n-4-3)  at (4,-6) {};
    \node[down] (n-4-4)  at (6,-6) {};  

    \foreach \i [count=\xi from 2] in {1,...,2}
        \foreach \j [count=\xj from 2] in {1,...,3}
           \draw (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\xi-\j);

     \foreach \j [count=\xj from 2] in {1,...,4}
           \draw[thick,dotted] (n-3-\j) -- (n-4-\j);


    \foreach \i [count=\xi from 2] in {1,...,3}
        \foreach \j [count=\xj from 2] in {1,...,2}
             \draw (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\i-\xj);

   \foreach \i [count=\xi from 2] in {1,...,4}
            \draw[thick,dotted]  (n-\i-3) -- (n-\i-4);

\draw (n-4-1) -- (n-4-2) (n-4-2)--(n-4-3) ;
\draw (n-1-4) -- (n-2-4) (n-2-4)--(n-3-4) ;
\foreach \i in {1,...,4} {%
     \draw (n-\i-4)--++(1.5,0) ;
     \draw (n-4-\i)--++(0,-1.5) ;
     }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To do something perhaps better. I removed a large part of the code. Your problem now is to draw the vertices and the arrows inside the circles. I wrote all the labels to help you if you want to designe some nodes

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[darkstyle/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=10mm}]
  \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,4} 
       {%\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\x - 5 *  \y +21}
       \node [darkstyle,label=45:$n-\x-\y)$]  (n-\x-\y) at (2*\x,2*\y) {};} 

  % \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
  %   \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {0,...,3}  
  %     \draw (n-\x-\y)--(n-\x-\yi) (n-\y-\x)--(n-\yi-\x) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain the for loop that you have used so that I can try to add the horizontal lines at the last row?

Comment: I think it's more easy to add the last row by hand without a loop. The problem is that the picture is not symmetric some lines are dotted etc. Perhaps a better way is to determine the coordinates of the nodes with a loop, then to draw the nodes and the edges. Have ou an algorithm to place the arrows ?