# a matrix of tikz objects

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use the following code to draw a tikz object.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Axis
    \draw (-0.5,0) -- (5.0,0);
    \draw (0,-0.5) -- (0,2.5);

    \node (rect) at (1.5,2) [draw,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=2cm,fill=gray!50] {};
    \node (rect) at (2.5,1) [draw,minimum height=0.65cm,minimum width=3cm,fill=gray!50] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

and the object looks like -

[image]

What I would like to have is grid of such objects. 
So that in the grid at every location (1,1), (1,2)... (n,n) this object should be drawn.

Of course I can copy paste this code using scope and use `xshift, yshift` in order to place many of them. What I need to see how `10 x 10` grid or even `100 x 100` grid of such objects. However I would like to use a `for` loop to draw this grid of tikz nodes. I want to use the for loop mentioned in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61805/tikz-using-loop-to-draw-grid-of-nodes). However my tikz node consists of multiple nodes (2 lines and 2 rectangles).

Is it possible to draw the grid of objects using for loop?

Comment: You can take a look at `matrix` library, and the corresponding section of the manual. Of course you can also use a `\foreach` loop, wich can be more convenient of a large number of similar repeated nodes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed possible

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
    \foreach \y in {1,2,3}{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(3*\x,2*\y)}]
      \draw (-0.25,0) -- (2.5,0);
      \draw (0,-0.25) -- (0,1.25);
      \node (rect) at (.75,1) [draw,minimum height=0.325cm,minimum width=1cm,fill=gray!50] {};
      \node (rect) at (1.25,.5) [draw,minimum height=0.325cm,minimum width=1.5cm,fill=gray!50] {};
    \end{scope}
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Open for comments or better solutions!

Answer (score 3):

Just another solution with `pics` which can be used within `foreach` loops or `matrix`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
    myobject/.pic={
      \draw (-0.25,0) -- (2.5,0);
      \draw (0,-0.25) -- (0,1.25);
      \node (rect) at (.75,1) [draw,minimum height=0.325cm,minimum width=1cm,fill=gray!50] {};
      \node (rect) at (1.25,.5) [draw,minimum height=0.325cm,minimum width=1.5cm,fill=gray!50] {};
        }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
    \foreach \y in {1,2,3}{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(3*\x,2*\y)}]
      \pic{myobject};
    \end{scope}
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [column sep=3mm, row sep=3mm] {
      \pic{myobject}; &  \pic{myobject}; &  \pic{myobject}; \\
      \pic{myobject}; &  \pic{myobject}; &  \pic{myobject}; \\
      \pic{myobject}; &  \pic{myobject}; &  \pic{myobject}; \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: At least here you don't have to calculate the shift in function of the pic size...