# Repeating the same figure in rows in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to repeat the following figure say 3 times in rows, i.e., below one another preferably using a loop. How can I do that? Thanks!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\begin{document} 
   \begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going right,>=latex,node distance=0pt]
    \node[draw,rectangle,on chain,draw=white,minimum size=1.3cm]{};
    \node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=6,
    draw, rectangle split horizontal,text height=0.5cm,text depth=0.5cm,on chain,inner ysep=0pt] (wa) {};
    \fill[white] ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth,yshift=-\pgflinewidth]wa.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-15pt,yshift=\pgflinewidth]wa.south);
    \node at (wa.east) (A){};
    \draw [-latex] (A) --+(0:1) coordinate (B1);
    \node [draw,circle,on chain,minimum size=1cm] at (B1) (se1) {$n$};
    \draw[<-] (wa.west) --+(-20pt,0) node[left] {$\lambda_1$};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. Your code cannot be compiled by the people here without manual modification. Please complete the code.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61805 and http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/foreach/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `\foreach` loop and perform a vertical shift within a `scope` as follows. Note that you have to move the `start chain=going right` into the scope for the shift to work properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\begin{document} 
   \begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,node distance=0pt]
   \foreach \y [count=\n]in {0,2,4}{ 
   \begin{scope}[yshift = \y cm,start chain=going right]
    \node[draw,rectangle,on chain,draw=white,minimum size=1.3cm]{};
    \node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=6,
    draw, rectangle split horizontal,text height=0.5cm,text depth=0.5cm,on chain,inner ysep=0pt] (wa) {};
    \fill[white] ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth,yshift=-\pgflinewidth]wa.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-15pt,yshift=\pgflinewidth]wa.south);
    \node at (wa.east) (A){};
    \draw [-latex] (A) --+(0:1) coordinate (B1);
    \node [draw,circle,on chain,minimum size=1cm] at (B1) (se1) {$n$};
    \draw[<-] (wa.west) --+(-20pt,0) node[left] {$\lambda_\n$};
    \end{scope}
    }
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make lambdas to be denoted \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3 using the same counter in the loop?

Comment: Yes, of course, let me edit this.

Comment: I think I got it! multiplying by 2 in \y and changing the coordinates works. Thanks.