# How to create this circle grid in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I'm kind of newbie using tikz, guys! I need to draw a figure similiar to this! Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Are you able to do any part of it? A couple of nested `\foreach` loops, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61805/tikz-using-loop-to-draw-grid-of-nodes, should give you the grey circles easily enough.

Comment: I wasn't able to do any part of it! Sorry! Im newbie to tikz!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\colorlet{layer}{gray!50}
\colorlet{layerhl}{black!80} % highlighted layer
\tikzset{neuron/.style={draw=#1,circle,minimum width=2pt,inner sep=0pt}}
\newcommand\layer[3]% \layer{name}{size}{label}
  {\foreach \i in {1,...,#2}
     \foreach \j in {1,...,#2}
       \node[neuron=layer] (#1-\i-\j) at (\i,\j) {};
   \node[anchor=south] at (0.5*#2+0.5,#2+1) {#3};
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3pt,y=3pt]
  \layer{input}{28}{input neurons}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(34,2)}]
    \layer{first}{24}{first hidden layer}
  \end{scope}
  % Highlighted part
  \node[neuron=layerhl] at (first-2-24) {};
  \foreach \i in {2,...,6}
    \foreach \j in {24,...,28}
      {\node[neuron=layerhl] at (input-\i-\j) {};
       \draw[->,layerhl] (input-\i-\j) -- (first-2-24);
      }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```